# Display bounty message at the top of the question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, bounty-remarks

On a long question, where the bounty could be used to encourage people to invest time learning about the problem (like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887870/decrypting-message-with-a-spring-web-service-client)), the bounty message being located at the end of the question is less than optimal.  If the bounty message displayed at the top in addition to or instead of at the bottom of the question it might encourage responses for questions that otherwise might get ignored due to length.  I understand that this doesn't apply if someone is specifically looking to answer bounty questions, but not every person who sees the question may have that intent.

Comment: I think this is definitely worth trying.  I think the SO team could easily implement this at least as a trial and see if more bounty questions get successfully answered.

Comment: I'm marking this as [status-completed] because this was implemented a while ago (it looks like it might have been part of [the new post notices rollout in December 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/05/new-post-notices-improving-feedback-on-stack-overflow-questions/): "All notices are now above the question text"). The bounty message is currently displayed above the body of the question (but below the title), as can be easily confirmed by looking at [any question on the "Bountied" tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Bounties).

Answer (score 3):

I always felt it should be right after the question, before/after the tags and asker box, and definitely above the comments. Below the comments, as it is today, seems too far down, specially when I want to check when a bounty expires.

It is also possible to add that blue `+350` next to the title, as it appears on the rest of the side.

Answer (score 1):

Is this really needed when the bounty is displayed before the question title in the question list?

Comment: But not when you're on the page before you scroll down. And there are plenty of times they're longwinded, so it's a while before you get there.