# Improving bounty messages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, bounties, markdown

I just offered a bounty¹ and feel like ***the displayed message could be a lot improved*:**

- *No formatting support ?!* (bullet points, *please*…)
- I cannot edit the message : so much for typos, the missing paragraph break which makes the list awkwardly displayed, everything I think of just after posting, etc.
- Previewing it would have prevented much of that.

And regarding the bounty display altogether:

- In the question page, the bounty is barely visible on the bottom of it, that is, after some scrolling when the question is long.
- The message explaining why the bounty is in a small font, whereas to me it's an important part of it (the few categories are not *nearly* precise enough to describe why a question could need some more attention).

¹ on French Language & Usage, for  [Translating some rare irregular verbs?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2715/1514)

Here's what it looks like:

> [image: Imgur]

<sub>I can't quite believe there's SNAFU on SE, but my broken list looks terribly like it right now.</sub>

Comment: see [Give some love to the Bounty tool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133640/165773) feature request and other, linked to it: [Can we have a way to edit bounty text?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188/165773), [Line breaks/paragraphs for bounty text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124016/165773). See also [Display bounty message at the top of the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32998/165773), [Markdown help and preview for bounty text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141587/markdown-help-and-preview-for-bounty-text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141587/165773)

Comment: @gnat: Oh, right, thanks. I looked for them, but only ran into trivial "how bounty works" or "can't I really get a refund" questions. How comes the "related" ones seem to have nothing to do ?

Comment: [Related Questions not entirely related/useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90574/165773)

Comment: This is dupe of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188/152859) indeed, I just gave it a push hopefully the devs will come over this time.